# How do I access UnsafePointer of member field of a struct referenced by an UnsafePointer in Swift?

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

Given

```
public struct MIDIPacketList {
    public var numPackets: UInt32
    public var packet: (MIDIPacket)
}
```

I would like to access an UnsafeMutablePointer of packet, given I have an UnsafeMutablePointer. Merely getting a copy of the original packet member is easy, but not correct: I need the pointer itself.
  In C, what I would like to achieve is as simple as

```
MIDIPacket *packet = &packetList->packet;
```

How do I do the same in Swift?
  Note that while I think advancing by 4 bytes (size of UInt32) does most likely work as a hack, but it is an incorrect answer because of structure alignment issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
let packetList: UnsafeMutablePointer<MIDIPacketList> = ...

withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &packetList.pointee.packet) {
    packet in // UnsafeMutablePointer<(MIDIPacket)>
    // ...
}
```

Inside the closure, `packet` is a pointer to the `MIDIPacket`.