# Assigning values to tuple in for loop

Tags: swift

There is a tuple of UInt8's in a struct MIDIPacket.
Normal assignment is like this:

```
import CoreMIDI
let packet = MIDIPacket()
packet.data.0 = 0x02
packet.data.1 = 0x5f
```

and so on.

This tuple has length of ~128+. There is an array of values, converted, which I would like to assign to the packet beginning at a certain index.

```
let converted = [0x01, 0x02, 0x5e,...]
var k = packet starting index of assignment
for i in 0..<converted.count {
    packet.data(k) = converted[i]
    k += 1
}
```

How do I do this?
subscripting doesn't work: e.g. `packet.data[i]`, while I believe Mirror simply creates a copy of the packet, so assigning to it would not work..

```
let bytes = Mirror(reflecting: packet.data).children;
        for (_, b) in bytes.enumerated() {
                       
                   }
```

Comment: Swift guarantees that tuples of homogeneous types have a contiguous memory layout. You take advantage of this by using `UnsafeBufferPointer` to read/write to the tuple. However, this forces you to manually key in the count, which can be error prone, so be careful. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27456220/3141234

Comment: does swift pointer arithmetic correlate to bytes? e.g. if I was to increase the UnsafeBufferPointer by 1, would the pointer move on the the next byte in the tuple?

Comment: I would invite you to make a formal answer if you'd like, as the link you shared is similar but not identical to the current context and the code not too easy to understand (at least to a Swift novice).
e.g. I have trouble creating the UnsafeBufferPointer

Comment: " does swift pointer arithmetic correlate to bytes?" -> Only for `UnsafeRaw(Mutable)?(Buffer)?Pointer`. For all the rest, they're typed, and have their indices correlate to the positions of the items, which can be multiple bytes apart.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42667639/1187415

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no official API for doing this, but IIRC, tuples of homogeneous element types are guaranteed to have a contiguous memory layout. You take advantage of this by using `UnsafeBufferPointer` to read/write to the tuple.

Usually this requires you to manually hard-code the tuple's element count, but I wrote some helper functions that can do this for you. There's two variants, a mutable one, which lets you obtain an `UnsafeBufferPointer`, which you can read (e.g. to create an `Array`), and a mutable one, which gives you a `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer`, through which you can assign elements.

```swift
enum Tuple {
    static func withUnsafeBufferPointer<Tuple, TupleElement, Result>(
        to value: Tuple,
        element: TupleElement.Type,
        _ body: (UnsafeBufferPointer<TupleElement>) throws -> Result
    ) rethrows -> Result {
        try withUnsafePointer(to: value) { tuplePtr in
            let count = MemoryLayout<Tuple>.size / MemoryLayout<TupleElement>.size
            
            return try tuplePtr.withMemoryRebound(
                to: TupleElement.self,
                capacity: count
            ) { elementPtr in
                try body(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: elementPtr, count: count))
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    static func withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Tuple, TupleElement, Result>(
        to value: inout Tuple,
        element: TupleElement.Type,
        _ body: (UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<TupleElement>) throws -> Result
    ) rethrows -> Result {
        try withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &value) { tuplePtr in
            let count = MemoryLayout<Tuple>.size / MemoryLayout<TupleElement>.size
            
            return try tuplePtr.withMemoryRebound(
                to: TupleElement.self,
                capacity: count
            ) { elementPtr in
                try body(UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: elementPtr, count: count))
            }
            
        }
    }
}

var destinationTouple: (Int, Int, Int, Int) = (0, 0, 0, 0) // => (0, 0, 0, 0)
var sourceArray = Array(1...4)

print("before:", destinationTouple)

Tuple.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer(to: &destinationTouple, element: Int.self) { (destBuffer: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int>) -> Void in
    sourceArray.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { sourceBuffer in
    //  buffer[...] = 1...
        destBuffer[destBuffer.indices] = sourceBuffer[destBuffer.indices]
        return ()
    }
}

print("after:", destinationTouple) // => (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: So suppose I would not like to start from index 0, but assign to the packet from let's say index 14, as in above example. Using destBuffer[14...17] = sourceBuffer[0...3] gives the error "Cannot assign through subscript: 'destBuffer' is a 'let' constant".

Comment: @Cheetaiean Are you sure you're using withUnsafe**Mutable**BufferPointer and not withUnsafeBufferPointer?

Comment: Yes, individual mutations such as destBuffer[1] = sourceBuffer[1] work correctly. However, assigning a range of values as above causes the problem. Attempting a for loop in the withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer closure causes even more bizarre errors.

Comment: Hmmmmm what if you try a `Range` like `14..<18` instead of a `ClosedRange` instead?

Comment: Brings a fatal error (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION).

Comment: Are you sure your destination tuple has at least 18 elements?

Comment: Yes, same errors for destinationTouple. 
e.g. Tuple.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer(to: &destinationTouple,... etc...) -> Void in 
    for i in 0...3 {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233136/discussion-between-alexander-and-cheetaiean).