# How to convert array to unsafe pointer

Tags: arrays, swift, mapkit, unsafe-pointers

I am creating an app that tracks a drive, so as you drive it records location and at the end, it shows a map of where you have been. I am using swiftUI's `MapKit` to display map data. In the process of displaying the information, I ran into a problem.

I plan to use MapKit polyline (`MKPolyline`) to show the location points but to initialize an `MKPolyline`, you must first have an unsafe pointer of either `MKMapPoint`s or `CLLocationCoordinate2D`s.

```swift
init(points: UnsafePointer<MKMapPoint>, count: Int)
init(coordinates: UnsafePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>, count: Int)
```

I have an array of coordinates but need an unsafe pointer instead. How do I go about converting them?

Comment: AFAIK you can simply pass your array of MKMapPoint `[MKMapPoint]` `(points: points, count: points.count)`

Comment: Yep, no need to create the unsafe pointer. Swift will take care of that for you.

Comment: I'm going to suggest that this duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68028656/why-can-i-pass-uint8-type-to-the-unsafepointeruint8-type-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Leo and Rob. They told me how. I just put the array right into the coordinates and swift handled the rest for me.

```swift
let Line = MKPolyline(coordinates: Locations, count: Locations.count)
```

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68028656/why-can-i-pass-uint8-type-to-the-unsafepointeruint8-type-parameter) for a more in depth answer

Comment: You didn't "figure it out". You were told the answer. Twice.

Comment: As a stylistic matter, in Swift, names of variables (such as your array) should always start with a lowercase letter. We capitalize types (names of classes, structs, enums, etc.), but variables should be in camelCase, starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @matt So sorry, i feel bad, i didn't mean that. yes Leo and Rob told me.